# UPS inside server room?

Tags: electrical-power, datacenter, ups

In my company we are considering to move our servers (some are mounted on 25U rack and some are tower servers) to a newly created room (underground, no windows) that contains 40 KVa UPS and redundant Air Conditioning System and will be continuously closed. There is also a Medium Voltage electical-power (MV 380V 60A) Panelboard inside this room.

Is there any considerable risk of electromagnetic interference if we put the servers in the same room with UPS and/or the MV ?

PS. the room is 3.5 by 3.5m. We don't have another room available and the servers are spread in multiple offices with people working around (bad I know).

Thank you in advance for your answers,

best regards

Answer (score 3):

No risk, but make sure the A/C got enought BTU for your servers, as such big UPS produce heat too.

I did a comparaison on a normal UPS, SmartAPC 1500 vs an Eaton 40kva, and both product follow the electromagnetic standard  of EN/IEC 62040-2.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, do you think that 2 units of 12000 BTU is enought ? The current configuration is that they work alternatively but could reconfigure that as needed.

Comment: @bydos Its hard to tell, a quick way to find is to check all technical spec of gears that will get there and check their respective BTU rating. It will give you an idea if ok or not

Comment: Good answer, and I will add that IT typically should not be responsible for the facilities portions of a server room.  We may size a UPS and layout the room, but we should be working with qualified electricians and A/C experts to determine what is needed.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I do understand that it is feasable to put the UPS along with the IT equipment under good A/C. However, if you could give more information about the risks related to the panelboard of medium voltage ?